# Lubridate fix the time units

Tags: r, lubridate

When we take the difference of two time, there is something going on automatically there in units.

```
> ymd_hms("2016-05-09 15:17:03") - ymd_hms("2016-05-09 15:17:04")
Time difference of -1 secs
> ymd_hms("2016-05-09 16:17:03") - ymd_hms("2016-05-09 15:17:04")
Time difference of 59.98333 mins
> ymd_hms("2016-05-10 16:17:03") - ymd_hms("2016-05-09 15:17:04")
Time difference of 1.041655 days
```

How can I fix the units without using `difftime` function.

So I can do the following:

```
VECTOR = c(ymd_hms("2016-05-10 16:17:03"),
           ymd_hms("2016-05-10 17:19:33"),
           ymd_hms("2016-05-10 19:55:03")
         )

diffs = diff(VECTOR)

IntervalsInHours = toHours(diffs)
```

Additionally, is there any way to know the units being used in a lubridate time object. For example,

```
> ymd_hms("2016-05-09 15:17:03") - ymd_hms("2016-05-09 15:17:04")
Time difference of -1 secs
```

The units used here are `seconds`.

Comment: multiply by 24 to get hours

Comment: What would be your expected output ? Do you want the output of all the above examples in hours?

Comment: I want to use `diff` function to take the time differences of a VECTOR of time points, only in the units specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"you want to use diff function to take the time differences between a VECTOR elements, only in the units specified"

pls try below code : (by int_diff function)

```
> VECTOR = c(ymd_hms("2016-05-10 16:17:03"),
+            ymd_hms("2016-05-10 16:17:04"),
+            ymd_hms("2016-05-10 17:19:33"),
+            ymd_hms("2016-05-10 19:55:03")
+ )
> as.numeric(int_diff(VECTOR))
[1]    1 3749 9330
> round(as.numeric(int_diff(VECTOR))/3600,2)
[1] 0.00 1.04 2.59
```

see, whatever the time interval min unit is seconds or not, it is always scaled by seconds as below.

```
> VECTOR = c(ymd_hms("2016-05-10 16:17:03"),
+            #ymd_hms("2016-05-10 16:17:04"),
+            ymd_hms("2016-05-10 17:19:33"),
+            ymd_hms("2016-05-10 19:55:03")
+ )
> as.numeric(int_diff(VECTOR))
[1] 3750 9330
> round(as.numeric(int_diff(VECTOR))/3600,2)
[1] 1.04 2.59
```

Answer (score 1):

please try below to transform the time difference into hours.

```
library(lubridate)
x=ymd_hms("2016-05-09 16:17:03") 
y=ymd_hms("2016-05-19 15:17:04")
diffs=as.duration(x-y)
IntervalsInHours=as.numeric(abs(diffs))/3600;IntervalsInHours
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use this way:

```
library(lubridate)
x=ymd_hms("2016-05-09 16:17:03") 
y=ymd_hms("2016-05-19 16:17:04")
diffs=as.duration(x-y);
IntervalsInHours=abs(diffs)/dhours(1);IntervalsInHours
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two functions in case anyone might find useful.

```
timeDiffUnitConvert = function(Diffs, to="day", roundingN = 1){      
  if(to == "day"){
    R = round(as.numeric(as.duration(Diffs))/3600/24,roundingN)
  } else if (to == "hour") {
    R = round(as.numeric(as.duration(Diffs))/3600, roundingN)
  } else if (to == "min") {
    R = round(as.numeric(as.duration(Diffs))/60, roundingN)
  } else if (to == "sec"){
    R = round(as.numeric(as.duration(Diffs)), roundingN)
  } else {
    stop("to which unit? it must be `day`, `hour`, `min` or `sec`.")
  }
  R
}

timeDiffVector = function(TimeVector, to="day", roundingN = 1, attachNaMode = "none"){
  R = timeDiffUnitConvert(diff(TimeVector), to = to, roundingN = roundingN)
  if(attachNaMode == "leading"){
    R = c(NA,R)
  } else if(attachNaMode == "trailing"){
    R = c(R,NA)
  } else{
    stop("check your attachNaMode: shall be either `leading` or `trailing`")
  }
  R
}
```